# How to efficiently loop over an image pixel by pixel in python OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, numba

What I want to do is to loop over an image pixel by pixel using each pixel value to draw a circle in another corresponding image.
[image]
My approach is as follows:

```
it = np.nditer(pixels, flags=['multi_index'])
while not it.finished:
    y, x = it.multi_index
    color = it[0]
    it.iternext()
    center = (x*20 + 10, y*20 + 10) # corresponding circle center
    cv2.circle(circles, center, int(8 * color/255), 255, -1)
```

Looping this way is somewhat slow. I tried adding the @njit decorator of numba, but apparently it has problems with opencv.

Input images are 32x32 pixels
They map to output images that are 32x32 circles
each circle is drawn inside a 20x20 pixels square
That is, the output image is 640x640 pixels

A single image takes around 100ms to be transformed to circles, and I was hoping to lower that to 30ms or lower

Any recommendations?

Comment: In this one only 4 circles should be drawn. How slow it is and how fast should it be? The input image is *2D* and the output is *3D*? Are input images squares? They only contain squares? Please add some sample (input) images.

Comment: maybe first run without `cv2.circle` to check if problem makes looping or `cv2.circle`

Comment: "efficiently" is irrelevant if you have few pixels. what performance do you have, and what do you need? -- `numba`'s `njit` only works on python code. any calls into library code (numpy, opencv) will **not** be optimized because that's **already compiled**

Comment: @CristiFati  The input images are grayscale raster images, and the output image is also a 2D pixels image. I usually work on 32 x 32 pixel images, but a single image with these dimensions takes around 100 ms to be transformed into circles. Applying that to videos, only FPS of 10 will be achieved in the best case scenario. I was hoping to optimize that to reach 30 FPS.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz My code currently yields 10 FPS for 32 x 32 images, and I was hoping to reach at least 30 FPS.

Comment: 32x32 images in one input image? How big are they? Is this constant or can it vary? The output image is as big as the input? Please provide all the details as in [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CristiFati The input is a 32x32 pixel images and the output is 640x640 pixels. Each pixel in the input image maps to a 20x20 pixels square in the output image. Each square of those contains a circle whose radius is proportional to the color retrieved from the original pixel.

Comment: use lookup tables then. pre-draw a circle for each level of 0 .. 255 and then copy those sprites as needed.

Comment: Use c++ and pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When:

- Dealing with drawings
- The number of possible options does not exceed a common sense value (in this case: 256)
- Speed is important (I guess that's always the case)
- There's no other restriction preventing this approach

the best way would be to "cache" the drawings (draw them upfront (or on demand depending on the needed overhead) in another array), and when the drawing should normally take place, simply take the appropriate drawing from the cache and place it in the target area (as @ChristophRackwitz stated in one of the comments), which is a very fast *NumPy* operation (compared to drawing).

As a side note, this is a generic method not necessarily limited to drawings.

But the results you claim you're getting: *~100 ms* per one *32x32* image (to a *640x640* circles one), didn't make any sense to me (as *OpenCV* is also fast, and 1024 circles shouldn't be such a big deal), so I created a program to convince myself.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import itertools as its
import sys
import time

import cv2
import numpy as np


def draw_img_orig(arr_in, arr_out):
    factor = round(arr_out.shape[0] / arr_in.shape[0])
    factor_2 = factor // 2
    it = np.nditer(arr_in, flags=["multi_index"])
    while not it.finished:
        y, x = it.multi_index
        color = it[0]
        it.iternext()
        center = (x * factor + factor_2, y * factor + factor_2) # corresponding circle center
        cv2.circle(arr_out, center, int(8 * color / 255), 255, -1)


def draw_img_regular_iter(arr_in, arr_out):
    factor = round(arr_out.shape[0] / arr_in.shape[0])
    factor_2 = factor // 2
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(arr_in):
        for col_idx, col in enumerate(row):
            cv2.circle(arr_out, (col_idx * factor + factor_2, row_idx * factor + factor_2), int(8 * col / 255), 255, -1)


def draw_img_cache(arr_in, arr_out, cache):
    factor = round(arr_out.shape[0] / arr_in.shape[0])
    it = np.nditer(arr_in, flags=["multi_index"])
    while not it.finished:
        y, x = it.multi_index
        yf = y * factor
        xf = x *factor
        arr_out[yf: yf + factor, xf: xf + factor] = cache[it[0]]
        it.iternext()


def generate_input_images(shape, count, dtype=np.uint8):
    return np.random.randint(256, size=(count,) + shape, dtype=dtype)


def generate_circles(shape, dtype=np.uint8, count=256, rad_func=lambda arg: int(8 * arg / 255), color=255):
    ret = np.zeros((count,) + shape, dtype=dtype)
    cy = shape[0] // 2
    cx = shape[1] // 2
    for idx, arr in enumerate(ret):
        cv2.circle(arr, (cx, cy), rad_func(idx), color, -1)
    return ret


def test_draw(imgs_in, img_out, count, draw_func, *draw_func_args):
    print("\nTesting {:s}".format(draw_func.__name__))
    start = time.time()
    for i, e in enumerate(its.cycle(range(imgs_in.shape[0]))):
        draw_func(imgs_in[e], img_out, *draw_func_args)
        if i >= count:
            break
    print("Took {:.3f} seconds ({:d} images)".format(time.time() - start, count))


def test_speed(shape_in, shape_out, dtype=np.uint8):
    imgs_in = generate_input_images(shape_in, 50, dtype=dtype)
    #print(imgs_in.shape, imgs_in)
    img_out = np.zeros(shape_out, dtype=dtype)
    circles = generate_circles((shape_out[0] // shape_in[0], shape_out[1] // shape_in[1]))
    count = 250
    funcs_data = (
        (draw_img_orig,),
        (draw_img_regular_iter,),
        (draw_img_cache, circles),
    )
    for func_data in funcs_data:
        test_draw(imgs_in, img_out, count, func_data[0], *func_data[1:])


def test_accuracy(shape_in, shape_out, dtype=np.uint8):
    img_in = np.arange(np.product(shape_in), dtype=dtype).reshape(shape_in)
    circles = generate_circles((shape_out[0] // shape_in[0], shape_out[1] // shape_in[1]))
    funcs_data = (
        (draw_img_orig, "orig.png"),
        (draw_img_regular_iter, "regit.png"),
        (draw_img_cache, "cache.png", circles),
    )
    imgs_out = [np.zeros(shape_out, dtype=dtype) for _ in funcs_data]
    for idx, func_data in enumerate(funcs_data):
        func_data[0](img_in, imgs_out[idx], *func_data[2:])
        cv2.imwrite(func_data[1], imgs_out[idx])
    for idx, img in enumerate(imgs_out[1:], start=1):
        if not np.array_equal(img, imgs_out[0]):
            print("Image index different: {:d}".format(idx))


def main(*argv):
    dt = np.uint8
    shape_in = (32, 32)
    factor_io = 20
    shape_out = tuple(i * factor_io for i in shape_in)
    test_speed(shape_in, shape_out, dtype=dt)
    test_accuracy(shape_in, shape_out, dtype=dt)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Notes**:

- Besides your implementation that uses *np.nditer* (which I placed in a function called *draw_img_orig*), I created 2 more:

  - One that iterates the input array *Python*icly (*draw_img_regular_iter*)
  - One that uses cached circles, and also iterates via *np.nditer* (*draw_img_cache*)
- In terms of tests, there are 2 of them - each being performed on every of the 3 (above) approaches:

  - Speed: measure the time took to process a number of images
  - Accuracy: measure the output for a *32x32* input containing the interval ***[0, 255]*** (4 times)

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q071818080]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
>
> Testing draw_img_orig
> Took 0.908 seconds (250 images)
>
> Testing draw_img_regular_iter
> Took 1.061 seconds (250 images)
>
> Testing draw_img_cache
> Took 0.426 seconds (250 images)
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> cache.png
> code00.py
> orig.png
> regit.png
> ```

Above there are the speed test results: as seen, **your approach took a bit less than a second for 250 images!!!** So I was right, I don't know where your slowness comes from, but it's not from here (maybe you got the measurements wrong?). 
The regular method is a bit slower, while the cached one is ***~2X*** faster. 
I ran the code on my laptop:

- *Win 10 pc064*
- *CPU*: *Intel i7 6820HQ @ 2.70GHz* (fairly old)
- *GPU*: not relevant, as I didn't notice any spikes during execution

Regarding the accuracy test, all (3) output arrays are identical (there's no message saying otherwise), here's one saved image:

[image: img0]

Comment: Turns out I was not calculating the FPS accurately. The proper measurement was 170 FPS without caching. After caching the circles, the FPS was 270. Thanks a lot buddy <3